# Quelle est l'origine du mot « voler » ?

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, étymologie, homonymes

Je souhaite connaitre l’étymologie du mot « voler ». Pourquoi le fait de voler dans les airs emploie le même mot que voler quelques choses à quelqu'un ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selon [Littre](https://www.littre.org/definition/voler.2)

**Prendre furtivement ou par force la chose d'autrui** :

> Mot récent pour lequel on disait embler, rober, larroner, et qui ne
> s'est introduit que vers la fin du XVIe siècle.
> D'après Diez, c'est
> une abréviation du lat. involare, voler, dérober, que les
> étymologistes latins, à tort ou à droit, expliquent, non, comme il
> dit, par volatu rapere, mais par vola, la paume de la main : mettre
> dans la paume de la main.
> Mais comment se fait-il que involare, qui a
> donné embler, ait donné aussi voler par aphérèse ; et surtout comment
> se fait-il que ce mot ne se trouve pas dans les anciens textes, quand
> ce n'est guère que dans l'antiquité que l'aphérèse a pu se faire ?
> Il n'y a pas lieu de sortir de la forme du mot : voler, au sens de
> dérober, est simplement une dérivation figurée de voler, chasser à
> l'oiseau ; on le dit à l'actif : voler une perdrix.

et [aussi](https://www.littre.org/definition/voler)

**Se soutenir, se mouvoir en l'air par le moyen des ailes** :

> Wallon, volé ; provenç. et espagn. volar ; ital. volare ; du lat.
> volare.

- [Voir aussi](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/voler) (wiktionnaire) :

> (verbe 1) Du latin volare (« voler dans l’air »). (881) volat (« vola
> »).
>
> (verbe 2) Du précédent, avec spécialisation du sens transitif en
> termes de fauconnerie. Il a supplanté rober (« dérober par force »),
> usuel jusqu’au XVIe siècle et embler (« dérober par la ruse »), usuel
> jusqu’au XVIIe siècle.

Les références les plus exhaustives que je connais sont dans le TLFi :

- [Voler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voler)(1) (dans l'air)
- [Voler](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voler/1)(2) (dérober)

Answer (score 2):

Pour préciser le changement de sens de *voler* (dans les airs) à *dérober*, voici l'explication de Walther von Wartburg, le linguiste suisse, auteur du *Dictionnaire étymologique du français*.

Im französischen wird das Verbum seit dem 12. Jh. gebraucht im Sinne „mit dem Falken (usw) jagen“, und zwar intransitiv *voler* (sowohl vom Falken, wie vom Jäger gesagt), *voler a un oiseau*, *voler d'un oiseau*, *voler d'un oiseau de proie a un oiseau*. Zu dieser Verwendung gesellt sich erst im 16 Jh. ein transitiver Gebrauch : *ils* (les oiseaux de chasse) *ne volent indifferemment tous oyseaux, mais un chacun d'eux s'attache à l'oyseau, à la chasse duquel il est addonné* (EstL 1570). Er muss aber doch etwas älter sein, denn aus ihm erklärt sich der Gebrauch von *voler* im Sinn „stehlen“ (seit 1549, die Ableitung *volerie* seit 1541). *voler* tritt nun in dieser Bedeutung an die Stelle von *rober*. Es überrascht, dass *rober*, dessen letzter Beleg von 1613 stammt und das noch von Amyot und den Dichtern der Pleiade gebraucht wird, sich in so kurzer Zeit völlig verdrängen lässt. Es hält sich noch in einigen Mundarten, besonders im frpr. und im occit. Daneben tritt an seine Stelle auch das seit dem 14. Jh. belegte *dérober*.

Je traduis :

En français, le verbe est employé depuis le 12e siècle au sens de « chasser au faucon (etc.) » en tant que verbe intransitif (il se dit à la fois du faucon et du chasseur), *voler a un oiseau*, *voler d'un oiseau*, *voler d'un oiseau de proie a un oiseau*. A cet emploi s'associe au 16e siècle un usage transitif : *ils* (les oiseaux de chasse) *ne volent indifferemment tous oyseaux, mais un chacun d'eux s'attache à l'oyseau, à la chasse duquel il est addonné* (EstL 1570). Il doit cependant être plus ancien car c'est cet usage qui explique *voler* au sens de « stehlen, to steal » (depuis 1549, le dérivé *volerie* depuis 1541). *voler* apparaît alors dans ce sens à la place de *rober*. Il est surprenant que *rober*, dont la dernière attestation remonte à 1613 et qui est encore utilisé par Amyot et les poètes de la Pléiade, ait été entièrement écarté en un laps de temps si court. Il se maintient encore dans certains dialectes, notamment dans le franco-provençal et l'occitan. Il est également remplacé par *dérober*, attesté depuis le 14e siècle.

EstL 1570 se réfère à *L'agriculture et maison rustique de Maîtres Charles Estienne et Jean Liebault Docteurs en médecine*